# Limit the sum only on the top 10 amount

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a mysql  table with that is called transactions and have the following fields: user (varchar), amount (float).

I want to make a group by like this

```
select `user`
     , sum(`amount`) as s
from (
  select * 
  from `transactions`
  order by `amount` desc
) t group by `user`, s
```

but I want to limit the sum only on the top 10 amounts.
Is it possible to do that with plain sql?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use `limit` and don't group by sum:

```
select `user`
     , sum(`amount`) as s
from (
  select * 
  from `transactions`
  order by `amount` desc
  limit 10
) t group by `user`
```